# Does this PHP syntax exist in JavaScript? function(var = null)

Tags: php, javascript, variables, syntax

In PHP, I have functions set variables to null if the parameter is not passed.  For example:

Function call:

```
myExample(8);
```

Function definition:

```
function myExample($var1, $var2 = null);
```

Expected result:

```
$var 1 = 8;
$var 2 = null;
```

Does similar syntax exist in JavaScript?  I tried doing it straight up and it didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, no. You can't assign a default value in the function declaration.

But:

```
function myExample($var1, $var2) {
}

myExample(1);
```

Will cause `$var2` to be `undefined` inside the function.

Comment: i think you can do as i did in the example: it's not the same but has the same effect

Answer (score 1):

In javascript you can pass any number of arguments you want to a function withouth needs to declare them. you can access them with the variable arguments which is kind like an array(it has a length property but in reality is an object)

you can do:

```
function yourfunction (var1){
    var var2 = null;
    if (arguments.length>1){
         var2 = arguments[1];
    }
}
```

this is quite like what you do in php, because if you don't pass a second argument, var2 is null, otherwise it is equal to the second argument

look [here](http://www.seifi.org/javascript/javascript-arguments.html) for full reference

EDIT a tipical example is the a function that sums all of his arguments, regardless of the number of them. I found it in several book on javascript. If you want to read more some good boks are: object oriented javascript and javascript patterns both by stoyan stefanov and the usual Javascript: the good parts

```
  function sumValues() {
   var sum = 0;
   for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    sum += arguments[i];
   } 
   return sum;
  }
```

Comment: Neat!  This will come in handy in the future.  Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

No it doesn't.

To allow for optional arguments, just specify them. If they are not supplied, they are defined as undefined.

Eg.

```
Func = function(arg, opt_arg)
{
    Alert(arg + ' ' + opt_arg);
}

Func('test');// gives "test undefined"
```

Arguments are not mandatory like in php.

You can simply so this

```
 
If(opt_arg  != 'undefined)
```

To check if user supplied it